# Get the timestamp of INSERT SPARQL Query in GraphDB

Tags: sparql, graphdb

I am working on a realtime project using Ontotext GraphDB which requires, the SPARQL queries are inserting into GRAPHDB every seconds, which is working perfectly. I am able to achieve that using RESTful API webapp with Flask. Here, my question is while doing the SELECT query in order to select the specific data, is it possible to retrieve the timestamp of the INSERT Query happened to GraphDB and if possible, how to do a select query for getting specific data between a time period. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. I mean, with SPARQL you can query just the data that is inside the database, i.e. that are proper RDF triples. Even if a triple store would do it for, it would have to add metadata to each RDF triple that you inserted. So it's up to you to keep track of different versions of your data, some people use named graphs, others do different things ...

Comment: https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/data-history-and-versioning.html. They also support RDF*.

Comment: ok, nice - so they provide some plugin with two additional index components. That's what I thought how to do it if the feature exists. I also like the filtering option.

Answer (score 2):

You could use GraphDB history plugin. You may read more about it using following link: https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/enterprise/data-history-and-versioning.html?highlight=history%20plugin